# How do I push to Github if I have previously committed a large file which has become small after more commits?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, rstudio, git-lfs

I have around 4 commits that need to be pushed to Github. Out of the 4 commits, I had committed a large file(over 100 MB) in the first commit, which has become smaller(65MB) in the fourth commit. But now when I try to push these commits there is an error saying that I can't commit files over 100MB.

I tried using GitHub Desktop to push these commits but that had the same error. I read about Git LFS but from what I have understood, this works only for a single file. I want the other changes in the commits to be pushed too. How do I go about this?

PS: I am mostly using RStudio's inbuilt 'Git' tab to commit, pull and push.

Comment: Files don't become "smaller" in/with Git. Every version of every file must be stored. Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository

Comment: Right now commits 1,2,3 all have the large file, and commit 4 does not. Since you never pushed any of the commits yet you can use interactive rebase to squash some commits. Perhaps squash the 4th into the 1st, or maybe just squash all 4 into one commit.